# Is there way to do a screen capture in Microsoft OneNote?

Tags: screen-capture, microsoft-onenote-2010

Is there a method or a plugin to do a screencapture (ideally similar to JingCast) with Microsoft OneNote?  Ideally it would be just a button similar to the one that turns on your webcam that would record whatever was happening on the screen at that point.

Comment: Are you trying to capture a single image of the screen or a video of something you are doing onscreen?

Comment: If you want video of your screen, as in creating a demo video for people to watch, I use http://camstudio.org/ its free and works pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "Windows Logo + s" for screen capture in MS OneNote. Video capture is not possible, must use 3rd party application.

Answer (score 0):

Try the snipping tool in windows 7  or print screen